Cloudfromation script erroring out on CodeDeployDeploymentGroup
I have a sample script which creates EC2, CodeBuild, CodeDeploy and its Deployment Group with ALB and then it goes further to setup with codePipeline, however I am getting an error on  CodeDeployDeploymentGroup stage,
Error -
CodeDeployDeploymentGroup
CREATE_FAILED
Likely root cause
The target group name arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:363010889649:targetgroup/SampleTG/75497adb8b9bc9b8 specified in targetGroupInfoList exceeds the maximum allowed length of 32 characters.
here is the sample script
The sample  script is here 
what could be the issue? I have tried shorting the names, so I am not sure what could be the problem here.

Hello and welcome to SO. You should not post links to the code, instead, add the the piece of the code that's important to your question. Check on how to ask good questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

As seen in the CloudFormation documentation you should use the Name property of the target group, or the TargetGroupName attribute with the Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function, as shown in the following example
In your code, inside CodeDeployDeploymentGroup, you're using:
TargetGroupInfoList:
  - Name: !Ref MyTargetGroup

which returns the ARN of the target group. Instead, as written in the documentation, you should use Fn::GetAtt to get the name of the group so that it would look like this:
TargetGroupInfoList:
  - Name: !GetAtt MyTargetGroup.TargetGroupName


Thank you so much for your clarification Caldazar
